# Understanding mouse DPI and Poll Rate

Tags: mouse

### motivation

Hi there, I have been curious about what the real definitions of mouse DPI and poll rate are as well as what type of information is sent across by the mouse to the computer. I am curious because I'd like to be able to understand what the benefits or detriments there are to changing different parameters of a mouse. These motivations are coming from playing FPS games on a computer.

### my understanding

**sent information**

From what I can gather a mouse would most likely sending be sending over mouse movement deltas to the computer. These deltas represent in some form how much the mouse's movement has changed, so that if your mouse is still it would be sending over (0, 0) and if you were to move it a little to the right then it would send over (0, +3) or something like that for a few updates.

I don't believe it would be absolution position on the screen as then the mouse would have to be aware of what the dimensions of the screen are. These mouse delta's would then be received by the computer and based on the cursors current position, it allows us to update it to a new position through software

**DPI**

Currently my understanding of dpi is that it stands for "dots per inch". As discussed in other articles and questions on this site many state that the dpi is in 1 to 1 correspondence with screen pixels.

If this were the case then with an 800 dpi mouse, moving the mouse 1 inch in the physical world corresponds to moving a distance of 800 pixels on the screen. If this were true, then plugging a mouse into computer with a square monitor of size 800x800px would produce a sensitivity twice as fast as it being plugged into 1600x1600px monitor computer. (with both monitors being the same physical size)

Before reading these articles I believed that DPI was an attribute that is invariant across monitor sizes and resolutions, and usually just made sure that all mouse parameters matched when plugging into a new computer, and that seemed to yield the same results on the different computers.

My personal hunch is that since nowadays we are dealing with optical mice that have image sensors, that this DPI refers to the DPI of the [image sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor) in the mouse that can be changed virtually.

If we had mouse A that has 4 dpi and a square sensor which is 1x1inch and it takes a snapshot of the top of the mousepad that looks like this (pixels separated by orange for clarity):

[image]

then we would be able to detect movements using this grey imperfection

If our sensor was set at 2dpi it would report:

[image]

which wouldn't be able to detect movements using the grey imperfection as the resolution isn't high enough.

If this is truly how dpi works, then on average a lower dpi mouse dpi will detect less movements and overall will produce a lower sensitivity

**poll rate**

Mouse A: 5hz poll rate
Mouse B: 10hz poll rate

From what I understand poll rate is the rate that the mouse send over information packets to the computer through the USB port.

Even though mouse B sends information twice as fast as mouse A the deltas would be half as large and thus the overall sensitivity shouldn't change.

Even if mouse sensitivity doesn't change, it would be able to detect changes in movement quicker, and thus giving you snappier and more reactive mouse movements.

**mouse grabbing applications**

If we assume that dpi is relative to screen pixels, then dpi might not entirely make sense because the mouse is not actually moving across the screen as there is no cursor to be found (think fps game where you can spin indefinitely). So I'm assuming that these types of applications might just read from the mouse's output delta's directly which supports the mouse delta output.

### my questions

As I've stated, these are my understandings and ideas about how mouse sensitivity works. I am hoping that for each of the sections I've written about, if anyone understands them in fuller detail or flaws in my understanding then they could help me correct my understanding or point me to further articles.

### references

To try and understand how this all works I read this article on what an [optical mouse](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/optical-mouse) then I used the [zowie ec3-c mouse](https://zowie.benq.com/en-ca/mouse/ec3-c.html) as a reference point, and looking at it's sensor  [3360 sensor](https://www.pixart.com/products-detail/10/PMW3360DM-T2QU), and it's [datasheet](https://www.epsglobal.com/Media-Library/EPSGlobal/Products/files/pixart/PMW3360DM-T2QU.pdf?ext=.pdf#page=18) where it talks mouse deltas in the register table.

Comment: You gotta love the use of the word mickey https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse#Mouse_speed

Comment: Raw Bluetooth Mouse Data: https://www.cs.ucf.edu/~xinwenfu/paper/BH13_Fu.pdf

Comment: https://youtu.be/xWB9dP1AtDU?t=463

Comment: This is my go-to "how a mouse works" video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAaESb4wTCM after watching this, it should answer all of your questions.